# Several issues with colorbox

Tags: colorbox

Just found this plugin the other day and am attempting to use it but finding some really strange problems.

1. there's no overlay around the color box when it opens
2. There is no next or previous buttons
3. The image numbers are 1 more than they should be (in other words image 1 shows as image 2 of 18, and in fact there are only 17 images in the test I am running)

the code is this:

$('a').colorbox({ rel:'group1', arrowKey: true, slideshow: true, slideshowAuto: false });

and an example of one of the images is:

<a rel='group1' href='/members/photo.php?id=22' title='the dogs'>
<img src='/userdocs/6/2012-01-02/thumb/dogs.jpg' width='100' height='100' title='the dogs' />
</a>

Comment: It's extremely widely used. The first two problems sound like CSS issues.  Posting a link to your site would help a lot.

Comment: Don't have this live where anyone can see it Kevin, let me look into the css

Answer (score 1):

1. (*) The colorbox library comes with a set of (background) images. These images must be located in the subfolder 'images' of the folder where the file colorbox.css is loaded from. A set of these images can be found in the downloaded archive at /colorbox/example1/images/.
2. Load the colorbox CSS before the colorbox JS.
3. Load the colorbox JS after jQuery JS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the overlay around the box not showing up. When I moved my reference  to the colorbox.css file ahead of my main.css, it fixed the issue.

Make sure you copy the desired images and colorbox.css file to the same directory as where you reference the colorbox .js file (e.g. jquery.colorbox.js). There are 5 versions based on the various examples use the images folder and colorbox.css file from your favorite. And make sure you are correctly referencing the colorbox.css file high enough in your  includes.